# php error inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forum

I am new to PHP, now I am developing a mini forum
I have made posts a option, the problem is after login and going to enter a post I can't post, it redirect me back to login page ad force sign-me-out. The code doesn't even have a redirection to login page

```
<?php
   ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
   $hostname = "localhost";
   $userDB = "root";
   $password = "";
   $databaseName = "forum";
   $con = mysql_connect($hostname, $userDB, $password) or die("failed to connect");
   mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con) or die("failed to connect with database");
   mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
   $myposts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Post']);
   $query= "insert into post ( posts , date )
       values ('".$myposts."' , now())";

   if(mysql_query($query)===true)
   {
      echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=posts.php" />';
   }
   else 
   { 
      echo "no permission to post"; 
   }
   mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: If you are new to PHP, then start learning about `PDO` now, before wasting your time learning how to use `mysql_*` function which are deprecated.

Comment: use SESSION variables

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted that would redirect you.  You obviously have some other code that is doing it.  Are you using a framework?

Comment: WTH... echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=posts.php" />';

Comment: agree with @Qǝuoɯᴉs if your new you should also start looking at the best practices, also a good way also for a forum etc look at laravel, Slim PHP etc this will take security etc and help you tons

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Qǝ uoɯᴉs about learning `PDO` ([docs](http://php.net/pdo) & [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers))for php,cause its better than mysql_* functions(even for beginners).

Also use [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) &  cookies for login data

Then about that redirecting I have a few things:
There are a few ways to redirect a page in php like

1. using meta refresh(like you have used)
2. using javascript like

   `<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location="http://www.google.com";</script>'`
3. with php [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

I think everyone would say 3rd one is the most appropriate one. For more information on this please read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255022/best-redirect-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I do this and works. Check it and tell me if still working.

 Change these lines:

```
if(mysql_query($query)===true)
{
 echo "<script>window.open('redirect.php','_self');</script>";
}
else 
{ 
 echo "No permission to post.<script>window.open('index.php','_self');</script>";
}
```

---

Greetings (: